# Applying root.xpath() with regex returns a lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, lxml

I'm generating a model to find out where a piece of text is located in an HTML file.

So, I have a database with plenty of data from different newspaper's articles with data like title, publish date, authors and news text. What I'm trying to do is by analyzing this data, generate a model that can find by itself the XPath to the HTML tags with this content.

The problem is when I use a regex within the xpath method as shown here:

```
from lxml import html

with open('somecode.html', 'r') as f:
    root = html.fromstring(f.read())

list_of_xpaths = root.xpath('//*/@*[re:match(.,"2019-04-15")]')
```

This is an example of searching for the publish date in the code. It returns a lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult instead of lxml.etree._Element.

Unfortunately, this type of element doesn't let me get the XPath to where is it locate like an lxml.etree._Element after applying `root.getroottree().getpath(list_of_xpaths[0])`.

Is there a way to get the XPath for this type of element? How?

Is there a way to lxml with regex return an lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult element instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you get an *attribute value* represented as an instance of `_ElementUnicodeResult` class.

If we introspect what `_ElementUnicodeResult` class provides, we could see that it allows you to get to the element which has this attribute via `.getparent()` method:

```
attribute = list_of_xpaths[0]
element = attribute.getparent()

print(root.getroottree().getpath(element))
```

This would get us a path to the element, but as we need an attribute name as well, we could do:

```
print(attribute.attrname)
```

---

Then, to get the complete xpath pointing at the element attribute, we may use:

```
path_to_element = root.getroottree().getpath(element)
attribute_name = attribute.attrname

complete_path = path_to_element + "/@" + attribute_name
print(complete_path)
```

FYI, `_ElementUnicodeResult` also indicates if this is actually an attribute via `.is_attribute` property (as this class also represents text nodes and tails as well).

Comment: Hmm, your solution is almost perfect! It returns me /html/head/meta[33]/@content. I'll try to find a way to get a prettier xpath, but you taught me some important things and I just got lots of ideas. Thanks alecxe!